# Google places callback function not executing in service.textSearch(request,callback);

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am new to google map's api and found myself unable to get the callback function to run. I have service and map defined as global variables, so that's how I access them. I tried every variation that I could think of but have been stumped for a couple hours now. I tried to follow the documentation, but the code still never executes the callback function.

```
/* var myLatLng = {lat: 44.977276, lng: -93.232266};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 14
        });
*/
// service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
// Both in the html file
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MyKeyIsInHere&libraries=places"></script>
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MyKeyIsInHere&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

function callback(results,status) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(status);
    if (results.status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var place = results[i];
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
}

$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // added **** for infor that was taken out
    var Key = "******";
    var form = $('#form :input');
    var curLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(***,***);
    var request;
    request = {
        location: curLoc,
        radius: parseInt(form[0].value),
        query: form[1].value,
        key: Key
    };
    service.textSearch(request,callback);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when you have multiple google api links at a time. 
For example

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyNum&callback=initMap&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

This causes the callback function to work improperly.